# Is it possible to use different colors for connected portions in Region Plot?

Tags: plotting, color

Following my previous question
[Move axis and tick labels in RegionPlot to the top, change border color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236158/move-axis-and-tick-labels-in-regionplot-to-the-top-change-border-color/236160#236160)
now, I have the following function

```
g := -(8 (1 + t) Sin[Sqrt[t] y] - (3 + t)^2 Sin[
        Sqrt[t] (2  π + y)])^2 + 
   270.86 (1 + t)^2 Cos[(2  π Sqrt[t])/3]^2 Sin[ π Sqrt[t]]^2;

RegionPlot[g >= 0, {y, 0, 2}, {t, 1, 3.8}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "y"}]
```

which the result is plot 1. I need to have a plot like the second plot. Since here the two portions are connected, the methods in [Move axis and tick labels in RegionPlot to the top, change border color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236158/move-axis-and-tick-labels-in-regionplot-to-the-top-change-border-color/236160#236160) do not help me. **Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give me a plot like 2 in this case? Or, is there a way to do it manually using drawing tools in Mathematica?**

**P.S**. *I need to have such a plot over a large domain, therefore, plotting over different range separately and then merging them do not help.*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

(1) Replace boundary lines with `White` lines that are 1 pixel thick, (2) [`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html), (3) [`ColorNegate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorNegate.html), and (4) [`ImageMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html). These 4 steps give a mesh objects with polygons separated but polygon coordinates are scaled up. We use [`CoordinateBounds`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBounds.html) on the original `RegionPlot` coordinates and  on the mesh coordinates and rescale mesh primitives back to original coordinates using [`RescalingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RescalingTransform.html).

```
ClearAll[separatePolygons]
separatePolygons = Module[{imgmesh = ImageMesh @ ColorNegate @ 
     Rasterize[Graphics[#[[1]] /. l_Line :> {AbsoluteThickness[1], White, l}], 
       ImageResolution -> 200], 
     cb = CoordinateBounds @ #[[1, 1, 1]], cbm}, 
   cbm = CoordinateBounds @ MeshCoordinates @ imgmesh; 
   MeshPrimitives[imgmesh, 2] /. p_Polygon :> RescalingTransform[cbm, cb] /@ p] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
rp = RegionPlot[g >= 0, {y, 0, 2}, {t, 1, 3.8}, PlotPoints -> 200];

Row[{Show[rp, FrameLabel -> {"t", "y"}, ImageSize -> 400], 
    Graphics[MapIndexed[{EdgeForm[{Thick, ColorData[97]@#2[[1]]}], 
        Opacity[.5], ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], #} &, separatePolygons @ rp], 
      FrameLabel -> {"t", "y"}, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]}, 
  Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
rp2 = RegionPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] <= 0, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]; 

Row[{Show[rp2, ImageSize -> 400], 
  Graphics[MapThread[{EdgeForm[{Thick, #2}], Opacity[.5], #2, #} &, 
    {#, ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range[Length @ #]]} &@
     separatePolygons @ rp2], 
  ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Replace `Cos[x] + Cos[y] <= 0` with `Cos[x] + Cos[y] >= 0` to get

[image]

**Note:** In versions prior to version 12, replace `cb = CoordinateBounds @ #[[1, 1, 1]]` with `cb = CoordinateBounds @ #[[1, 1]]`.