# How to separate the regions enclosed by curves

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, geometry

There are  three arbitrary curves that defined by three implicit functions. How to separate the 12 regions(one of them is the outside infinite region)

Although we can use image methods to distinguish it, the effect seem not so good.  Here we want to get the vector graphics. Thanks!

```
curves = ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, 
   x^2/36 + y^2 == 1, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0}, {x, -7, 
   7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black],PlotRangePadding -> None]
Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[curves]]
```

[image]

Test another way.(I don't know how to extract data from `BoundaryMeshRegion` directly.)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
curves = ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, 
    x^2/36 + y^2 == 1, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0}, {x, -7, 
    7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black], 
   Frame -> False,PlotRangePadding -> None];
Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[curves]];
domains = ImageMesh[curves, Method -> "DualMarchingSquares"];
pts = MeshCoordinates[domains];
lines = MeshCells[domains, "Multicells" -> True][[2]];
regs = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, #] & /@ lines;
outside = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, lines[[1]], lines[[2]]];
insides = 
  BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, lines[[#]]] & /@ Range[3, Length[regs]];
Graphics[{Gray, outside, 
  Thread[{ColorData[96] /@ Range[Length[regs] - 2], insides}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This [link](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/improved-visualization-labeling/venn-diagram.html?product=mathematica) should help, although this is not a typical Venn Diagram scenario. For instance, the light blue region on the left and the deep blue region on the right are in the same set but are supposed to be colored differently. Instead of `A, B, C` use `ImplicitRegion` for each of your equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method by @halmir also work for this case.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267223/72111

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eqns = {x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0, 
   x^2/36 + y^2 == 1};
plot = ContourPlot[eqns // Evaluate, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50];
lines = Cases[Normal@plot, _Line, -1];
data = Region`Mesh`SplitIntersectingSegments[lines];
pts = data[[1]];
splits = data[[2]];
segments = Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ splits, 1];
g = Graph[Range@Length@pts, UndirectedEdge @@@ segments, 
   VertexCoordinates -> pts];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
polys = Polygon[pts[[#]]] & /@ faces;
polys = Delete[polys, First@Ordering[Area@polys, -1]];
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range@Length@polys;
GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{RandomColor[], #} & /@ lines], 
  Graphics[Thread[{colors, polys}]]}]
```

[image]

- Test several arbitrary curves.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lines = Table[
   BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]] /@ Subdivide[200] // Line, 
   3];
data = Region`Mesh`SplitIntersectingSegments[lines];
pts = data[[1]];
splits = data[[2]];
segments = Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ splits, 1];
g = Graph[Range@Length@pts, UndirectedEdge @@@ segments, 
   VertexCoordinates -> pts];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
polys = Polygon[pts[[#]]] & /@ faces;
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range@Length@polys;
GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{RandomColor[], #} & /@ lines], 
  Graphics[Thread[{colors, polys}]]}]
```

[image]

- We use  `WindingCount` to remove the largest face.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eqns = {x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0, 
   x^2/36 + y^2 == 1};
plot = ContourPlot[eqns // Evaluate, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50];
lines = Cases[Normal@plot, _Line, -1];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics /@ lines // RegionUnion;
g = Graph[MeshPrimitives[reg, 1] /. Line -> Apply@UndirectedEdge, 
   VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[reg]];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
faces = Select[faces, WindingCount[Line@#, Mean@#] == 1 &];
GraphicsRow[{Graphics@lines, 
  Graphics[{{RandomColor[], Polygon@#} & /@ faces}]}]
```

- Add the dual grah.But I don't know why there are multiple edges in the dual planar graph.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[123];
eqns = {x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0, 
   x^2/36 + y^2 == 1};
plot = ContourPlot[eqns // Evaluate, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50];
lines = Cases[Normal@plot, _Line, -1];
reg = lines // RegionUnion;
g = Graph[MeshPrimitives[reg, 1] /. Line -> Apply@UndirectedEdge, 
   VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[reg]];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
index = FirstPosition[WindingCount[Line@#, Mean@#] & /@ faces, -1];
faces2 = Delete[faces, index // First];
graphics2 = Graphics[{{RandomColor[], Polygon@#} & /@ faces2}];
dual = Graph[VertexList@DualPlanarGraph[g], 
   EdgeList@DualPlanarGraph[g], 
   VertexCoordinates -> RegionCentroid@*Polygon /@ faces, 
   EdgeStyle -> White, VertexStyle -> White, 
   VertexSize -> Automatic];
dual2 = VertexDelete[dual, VertexList[dual][[First@index]]];
Show[graphics2, dual2]
```

[image]

Comment: `plot = ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 
     0, x^2/36 + y^2 == 1}, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}];
pts = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, -1];
poly = WindingPolygon[pts, "EvenOddRule"]` maybe another possible way.

Comment: `reg = MeshRegion[pts, Line@splits];
graph = MeshConnectivityGraph[reg, 0];
faces = PlanarFaceList[graph][[;; , ;; , 2]];
polys = Polygon[pts[[#]]] & /@ faces;
polys = Delete[polys, First@Ordering[Area@polys, -1]];
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range@Length@polys;
GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{RandomColor[], #} & /@ lines], 
  Graphics[Thread[{colors, polys}]]}]`

Answer (score 13):

```
eqns = {x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, x^2/36 + y^2 == 1, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0};

regions = eqns /. Equal -> LessEqual;

rp = RegionPlot[Evaluate@regions, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1], 
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], White]]
```

[image]

Use a slightly modified version of `separatePolygons` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236252/125):

```
ClearAll[separatePolygons]
separatePolygons = Module[
         {imgmesh = 
            ImageMesh @
              ColorNegate @
                Rasterize[Graphics[#[[1]]], ImageResolution -> 200], 
          cb = CoordinateBounds @ #[[1, 1, 1]], cbm}, 
        cbm = CoordinateBounds @ imgmesh;
        MeshPrimitives[imgmesh, 2] /. 
          p_Polygon :> RescalingTransform[cbm, cb] /@ p] &;

Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], #} &, 
    separatePolygons[rp]], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions prior to version 12.0, replace `cb = CoordinateBounds @ #[[1, 1, 1]]` with `cb = CoordinateBounds @ #[[1, 1]]`.

Answer (score 9):

Using the method in OP's update:

```
curves = ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, x^2/36 + y^2 == 1, 
    (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0}, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black], 
   Frame -> False];

imesh = ImageMesh[curves, Method -> "DualMarchingSquares"];

polygons13 = ReverseSortBy[RegionMeasure] @
  (MeshPrimitives[imesh, 1, Multicells -> True] /. Line -> Polygon @* Apply[Join]);

polygons = Join[{Polygon[# -> #2]& @@ (List @@@ #[[;;2]])}, #[[3;;]]]& @ polygons13;

Graphics[{RandomColor[], #}] & /@ polygons// Multicolumn[#, 3]&
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{RandomColor[], #} & /@ polygons, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Note:** The first two polygons in `polygon13` are the enclosing rectangle and the union of inside polygons:

```
Graphics[{RandomColor[], #}] & /@ polygons13[[;;2]]
```

[image]

Hence to the need to use the `Polygon[# -> #2]& @@ (...)` trick to get a polygon with a hole.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {x^2 + y^2 <= 16, x^2/36 + y^2 <= 1, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 <= 9};
b = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
     BooleanRegion[BooleanFunction[#, Length@a], 
      ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ a] & /@ (2^Range[1, 2^Length@a - 1]);
Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[14]@#2[[1]], #1} &, 
  Flatten[MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & /@ b]]]
```

Comment: Wonderful. Could you please add a brief verbal explanation on how you separated these regions? Thanks.

Comment: (+1) Use the `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to seperate the region is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

- Another way. Although it is not so elegant. We dilation the lines and use it to separate the plane.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
plot = ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 16 == 0, 
    x^2/36 + y^2 == 1, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 9 == 0}, {x, -7, 
    7}, {y, -7, 7}];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
dist = RegionDistance[reg];
ireg = ImplicitRegion[dist@{x, y} >= .01, {{x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}}];
dregs = ConnectedMeshComponents[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ireg, Method -> "Semialgebraic", 
    MaxCellMeasure -> .01]];
Graphics[
 MapIndexed[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][First@#2]], 
    EdgeForm[ColorData[97][First@#2]], #1} &, dregs]]
```

[image]

- For another curve.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{x0, y0} = {-5, 2}; 
eqns = {(x - 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 == (x0 - 2)^2 + (y0 - 1)^2, (x - 
       3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 == (x0 - 3)^2 + (y0 - 4)^2, (x - 5)^2 + (y + 
       8)^2 == (x0 - 5)^2 + (y0 + 8)^2};
plot = ContourPlot[eqns // Evaluate, {x, -10, 20}, {y, -10, 20}];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
dist = RegionDistance[reg];
ireg = ImplicitRegion[
   dist@{x, y} >= .015, {{x, -10, 20}, {y, -10, 20}}];
dregs = ConnectedMeshComponents[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ireg, Method -> "Semialgebraic", 
    MaxCellMeasure -> .001]];
Graphics[
 MapIndexed[{FaceForm[ColorData[97][First@#2]], 
    EdgeForm[ColorData[97][First@#2]], #1} &, dregs]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Here only a demonstrate of the ideas of @Karl.
- At first we spereate the plane by binary decompose method, after that we use `ConnectedMeshComponent` to seperate the disconneted regions.

```
ineqs = {x^2 + y^2 <= 16, 
   x^2/36 + y^2 <= 1, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 <= 9};
binarydecomposition = 
  Tuples[And@Through /@ {Not, Identity} /@ ineqs];
regs = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ binarydecomposition;
splits = 
  ConnectedMeshComponents@
     BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, 
      MaxCellMeasure -> .01] & /@ regs;
Graphics /@ 
 Table[{RandomColor[], reg, White, 
   MapIndexed[Text[Style[First@#2, 14], RegionCentroid@#1] &, 
    reg]}, {reg, splits}]
```

[image]

```
Table[{Blend[{White, ColorData[6][i]}, j/Length@splits[[i]]], 
   splits[[i, j]], White, 
   Text[Style[{i, j}, 8], RegionCentroid@splits[[i, j]]]}, {i, 1, 
   Length@splits}, {j, 1, Length@splits[[i]]}] // Graphics
```

[image]