# Colouring the "leaves" (self-intersections) of space curves

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I recently asked how to

[colour the "leaves" (self-intersections) of parametric curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295768/colouring-the-leaves-self-intersections-of-parametric-curves)

and got two great answers from `cvgmt` and `kglr`, allowing us to produce images of 2D parametric curves like this one:

[image]

I want to find a similar filling method for 3D space curves. Here are three of them:

```
crown = {Cos[0.3 #], Sin[0.3 #], 0.75 Sin[0.7 #]} &;

noeud = {2  Cos[#] - 2 Cos[3 #], 2  Sin[#] + 2 Sin[3 #], Sin[4 #]} &;

viviani = {Cos[#], Sin[#], 2 Sin[#/2]} &;
```

It follows my only partly successful attempt to fill 3D "leaves"

```
SpaceFilling[
  curve_,
  r_,   (* plot range *)
  p_,   (* polygon resolution *)
  op_,  (* opacity *)
  tr_,  (* tube radius *)
  st_,  (* polygon steps *)
  sm_   (* polygon smoothing *) ] :=
 
 Show[

  Graphics3D[{Opacity[op], EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Darker @ Red], 
    Map[Polygon[Flatten[MapAt[Reverse, #1, {2}], 1]] &, 
     Partition[
      Module[{dt = 
         Table[#1[[1]] + 1/st n (#1[[2]] - #1[[1]]), {n, 1, st}] & /@ 
          Transpose[{Table[curve[t], {t, 0., r, r /p}], 
            Table[curve[t], {t, r, 2. r, r/p}]}]},
       Do[
        dt = 
         Table[If[x =!= 1 && x =!= Length[dt] && y =!= 1 && y =!= st, 
           Mean[{dt[[x - 1, y]], dt[[x + 1, y]], dt[[x, y - 1]], 
             dt[[x, y + 1]]}], dt[[x, y]]], {x, 1, Length[dt]}, {y , 
           1, st}],
        {sm}];

       dt],
      {2, 2}, {1, 1}],
     {2}]}],
  
  ParametricPlot3D[curve[t], {t, 0, 2 r},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighter @ Gray],
    Axes -> False,
    Boxed -> False,
    BoxRatios -> 1,
    PlotPoints -> 128] /. Line -> (Tube[#, tr] &),
  
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.85],
  Boxed -> False,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  SphericalRegion -> True]
```

Applying `SpaceFilling` to a `noeud` curve looks promising, but as you rotate it, ugly polygon intersections emerge.

[image]

The contours of a `crown` curve are replicated nicely, but the polygons extend into the interior.

```
SpaceFilling[crown, 10 Pi, 100, 0.5, 0.02, 100, 100]
```

[image]

And the filling of the seemingly simple `viviani` curve is completely wrong.

```
SpaceFilling[viviani, 2 Pi, 100, 0.5, 0.04, 100, 10]
```

[image]

**My request**

I probably got stuck in a dead-end street, and we need a completely different approach (using region functions like in the 2D case). If this is impossible or too difficult, I would also accept an answer that significantly improves `SpaceFilling`, especially the polygon creation and smoothing method.

Comment: wrap `ParametricPlot3D[viviani[t], {t, 0, 4  Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 128]` with `ReplaceAll[ l_Line :> {Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Darker@Red],   Polygon @@ l, LightGray, Tube[#, .05] & @@ l}]`? (similarly with `noeud` and `crown`)

Comment: It functions perfectly for `noeud` and `viviani`, but not for `crown`. However, this is such an amazing improvement, that I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for editing @ `user444`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `crown` we can use the three-argument form of `ParametricPlot3D` to get the desired surface:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1, 1, v} crown[t], 
  {t, 0, FunctionPeriod[Rationalize @ crown[t], t]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Red], SphericalRegion -> True, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 128, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.85], Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400, 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint",   MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Gray, Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}] /. 
 Line[x_] :> Tube[x, .03]
```

[image]

For `viviani` and `noeud` we can post-process to replace `Line` objects with  `Polygon` and `Tube` objects:

```
lineToPolygonAndTube = ReplaceAll[l_Line :> 
     {Opacity[1], EdgeForm[],  FaceForm[Red, Red],
      Polygon @@ l, LightGray, Tube[#, .05] & @@ l}];

lineToPolygonAndTube@
 ParametricPlot3D[viviani[t],
  {t, 0, FunctionPeriod[Rationalize @ viviani[t], t]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Black, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 128, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Background -> GrayLevel[0.85], 
  ImageSize -> 400, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Replace `viviani` with `noeud` and `Opacity[1]` with `Opacity[.5]` to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you, kglr, for these marvelous solutions. Now there are only two space curves left in my portfolio which cause problems. If you know a solution for them, please post it as a second answer. First curve: `{Cos[4 #] Cos[#], Cos[4 #] Sin[#], 0.6 Cos[4 #]} &` with a period of 2 Pi

Comment: Second curve (Period 20 Pi): `{Cos[#]*(0.5 - Cos[Pi/3]) + Cos[#]*Cos[Pi/3]*Cos[0.9 #] + Sin[#]*Sin[0.9 #],
  Sin[#]*(0.5 - Cos[Pi/3]) + Sin[#]*Cos[Pi/3]*Cos[0.9 #] - Cos[#]*Sin[0.9 #], -Sin[Pi/3] + -Sin[Pi/3]*Cos[0.9 #] } &`